# Change FormBorderStyle without client area moving

Tags: c#

I have a floating borderless form that contains two buttons. When the user moves the mouse over the form, the FormBorderStyle changes to SizableToolWindow and then returns after a set time using a timer. When this happens the form shifts to accommodate the title bar and Form edge. I am able to compensate for this however when it happens you get a flicker of the form being shifted before being placed back into place.

Is there any way I can stop the window refreshing until after I have already shifted it back into place?

Here's my shifting code:

```
        if (this.FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
        {
            // Suspend layout of Form
            this.SuspendLayout();

            // Suspend layout of button controls
            this.cbBlankDisplay.SuspendLayout();
            this.btnPurgeMessages.SuspendLayout();

            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Left += this.change.Width;
            this.Top += this.change.Height;

            // Resume layout of buttons and Form
            this.btnPurgeMessages.ResumeLayout();
            this.cbBlankDisplay.ResumeLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout();
        }
```

Comment: From your code I assume "this" is the form and "change" is some constant Rectangle. You could add location change so it looks like the content isn't moving (might be dependent on style though).

Comment: change is a Size used to keep track of the distance that the top and left were shifted (calculated first time form loses it's border only). I then update the Left & Top positions of the Form to make up for the missing title and form surround. It works, but you can visually see the jitter of the form moving.

Comment: Doesn't a location change fix it then? (a little up and left?)

Comment: Changing a window's border style has a *lot* of side-effects.  Winforms can only do this by destroying the window and re-creating it again, now using the new style flags passed to the CreateWindowEx() winapi function.  Inevitably you will also see it flicker, physically the old window is gone and replaced by a new one, you cannot wish that away.  It is not like you cannot bypass that, doing something silly like overlapping the window with another one that displays a bitmap created from a screenshot.  Updating your machine to Windows 10 is a lot easier :)

Comment: @Hans Passant  I did consider creating a bitmap overlay or Creating a floating panel with transparent section at the top that only becomes visible with mouse over. Just wondering if there was a more simplistic method. I didn't realize the form was destoryed and re-created. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing as Hans Passant suggested and creating a duplicate of my ClientRectangle area which is displayed on an already transparent full screen overlay.
My MouseLeave Event just starts the Timer.

This is the Code in my MouseEnter Event:

```
    private void FloatingButtons_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow)
        {
            if (this.Tag is Bitmap)
            {
                Owner.overlay.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(
                    (Bitmap)this.Tag,
                    new Rectangle(
                        Point.Add(this.Location, this.change),
                        this.ClientRectangle.Size),
                    new Rectangle(this.Location, this.ClientRectangle.Size),
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel
                    );
            }
            this.Hide();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.cbBlankDisplay.SuspendLayout();
            this.btnPurgeMessages.SuspendLayout();
            if (this.change.Height == 0)
            {
                this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
                Rectangle scrPosition = RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
                this.change.Width = (scrPosition.Left - this.Left);
                this.change.Height = (scrPosition.Top - this.Top);
            }
            this.Left -= this.change.Width;
            this.Top -= this.change.Height;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            this.btnPurgeMessages.ResumeLayout();
            this.cbBlankDisplay.ResumeLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout();
            this.Show();
            if (this.Tag != null && this.Tag is Bitmap)
            {
                ((Bitmap)this.Tag).Dispose();
                this.Tag = null;
                Overlay.performUpdate = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code in my Timer_Tick Event:

```
        if (this.FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
        {
            // Create a bitmap the size of my Form
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);
            // Copy the form to the newly created Bitmap
            this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.Bounds.Size));
            // Create a rectangle of the Location and Size of the ClientArea
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((Point)this.change, this.ClientRectangle.Size);
            // The Owner Form contains a class that already performs overlays on the screen
            Owner.overlay.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(
                bmp,
                new Rectangle(
                    Point.Add(this.Location, this.change),
                    this.ClientRectangle.Size),
                rect,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel
                );
            // Store the Bitmap in the Tag for Disposal after being used
            this.Tag = bmp;

            // Now I can hide my Form and perform necessary changes
            this.Hide();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.cbBlankDisplay.SuspendLayout();
            this.btnPurgeMessages.SuspendLayout();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Left += this.change.Width;
            this.Top += this.change.Height;
            this.btnPurgeMessages.ResumeLayout();
            this.cbBlankDisplay.ResumeLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout();
            this.Show();
        }
```